# How can stacked bars be plotted?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I try to create a stacked bar plot with given values with the pgfplots package, but it shows some errors. Can anyone correct the given errors?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=15pt,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#Schedule Length},
    symbolic x coords={P1, P2, P3},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    xlabel={\#Processor}
    ]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(p1,73) (p1,44)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(p2,45) (p2,76)
  (p2,68) (p2,99) };
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(p3,9) (p3,26)
  (p3,45) (p3,35)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

One `\addplot` should not contain all values of e.g. `P1`, it should contain the three values for `P1`, `P2` and `P3` for one of the stacked bars, e.g.

```
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(P1,73) (P2,45) (P3,9)};
```

To stack the bars, create one such `\addplot` for every bar you want to add on top. Even though `P1` only has two bars, you need to specify the coordinate and e.g. set it to zero:

```
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(P1,0) (P2,99) (P3,35)};
```

One more note: Use the same case for the symbolic coordinates, i.e. don't mix `p1` and `P1`.

Your MWE then becomes

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=15pt,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#Schedule Length},
    symbolic x coords={P1, P2, P3},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    xlabel={\#Processor}
    ]

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(P1,73) (P2,45) (P3,9)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(P1,44) (P2,76) (P3,26)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(P1,0) (P2,68) (P3,45)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(P1,0) (P2,99) (P3,35)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image: resulting plot]

If you want the second bar of `P1` to be e.g. gray instead of red, you can set the second and third `P1` value to zero, instead of the last two:

```
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(P1,73) (P2,45) (P3,9)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(P1,0) (P2,76) (P3,26)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(P1,0) (P2,68) (P3,45)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(P1,44) (P2,99) (P3,35)};
```

[image: result2]

Comment: thank you, but i need the exact my query representation type diagram.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style=
{xshift=-15pt,yshift=-3pt,anchor=east,font=\footnotesize},
        xbar legend,
%         nodes near coords align={right},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1},
        enlarge y limits=false,
        bar width=35.5,width=10cm,height=11cm,
        % x axis
        xtick={1,2,3},
        xticklabels={p1,p2,p3},
        % y axis
        ymin=0,
        ylabel={Scheduling Length},
        xlabel={Processors},
        %yticklabels={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,500},
      ]
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=blue,
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange
1       40              18      07      00
2       34              36      19      00
3       09              17      09      10
      };
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=pink,
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange
1       40              18      07      00
2       34              36      19      00
3       09              17      09      10
};
      \addplot table [
      x=index,
      y=gray,
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange
1       40              18      07      00
2       34              36      19      00
3       09              17      09      10
      };
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=orange,
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange
1       40              18      07      00
2       34              36      19      00
3       09              17      09      10
      };
      %\legend{First one,Second one,Third,Fourth}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
```